# C++ Histogram error in last column

Tags: c++, histogram

Check my code and tell me the error in code. actually i was trying to print a histogram in C++. there things worked fine but there is an issue that in the last column of the stars,the value remains same to column 3.means if i give two different input values to third and fourth entry,their output is same but in two columns, I want to print their own values in their own columns, here is the code.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int f[4];
int main()
{
   int a, b, c, d, i;
   cin >> f[0] >> f[1] >>  f[2]>>f[3];
   int m = max(max(max(f[0],f[1]),f[2]),f[4]);
   for(int i=m;i>=1;i--)
   {
       for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
           if (f[j]<i) cout <<' ';
           else cout <<'*';
       cout<<endl;
   }
}
```

here is the output if i gave these inputs.

```
2,3,4,5
```

output:

```
  **
 ***
****
****
```

Answer (score 0):

When looking for the maximum element, you're looking at `f[4]`, which is outside the bounds of your array, resulting in Undefined Behavior.

You meant to use `f[3]`.